# ABAP Eclipse debugger, function keys missing

Tags: eclipse, debugging, abap

During a recent update, the function keys for debug actions for example single step(f5) step over(f6) return(f7) and resume(f8) disappeared.
It is only possible with the buttons or right click menu now.

**Can the function key assignments be recovered ?**

[image]

version info

[image]

**EDIT:**
An upgrade was available when i checked today. (What happened to check for updates on start ?)

The latest update  version 2.28.6 resolved the problem.

> ABAP Core Development Tools (Developer Edition)   2.68.6
>   com.sap.adt.core.devedition.feature.group

**EDIT 2:**
Problem has  recurred.
So the version of the plugin is not the problem.
Something causes the debugger key assignments to disappear.
Of interest is the fact I saved the standard debugger perspective with a different layout. is that somehow related ?

**EDIT 3:** Resetting the Debug perspective to standard recovered the keys.
I have f keys again for a week now

Comment: About EDIT2: might be. Try to re-save the perspective with a native layout. I am still assume it's key conflict, so try to assign another key.

Comment: resetting the perspective seems to be the solution

Answer (score 1):

Use standard Eclipse key binding functionality if some ABAP hotkeys got missing somehow.
Go to *Preferences >> General >> Keys*, find necessary Step commands and reassign keys if needed.

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't help then you have some hotkey conflicts in your system. I frequently have such troubles in other applications, when one app overlaps another.